# How to comment an SDF?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a way to add comments that aren't parsed to an SDF?

If so, perhaps this should be added to the [SDF 1.3 documentation](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.3.html).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/967/how-to-comment-an-sdf?/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The first line of the SDF documentation tells you that SDF is an XML file format ("The Simulation Description Format (SDF) is an XML file format"), hence you can comment it like any other XML file, i.e. using `<!-- comment -->`

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-21**:
Thanks.